# why din't computed don't track changes in this simple knockout app?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

[image]

The menu is what I want, when mouse over the left, the right should changes but doesn't.

Here is my simplified viewmodel:

```
var currentSelectIndex  = 0;

var AppModel = {
    CurrentIndex: ko.observable(currentSelectedIndex),
    OnMouseOver: function (data, event) {
        // change currentIndex or currentSelectedIndex here
        // CurrentSubCategory didn't updated
    },
    CurrentSubCategory: ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return AppModel.Menu[AppModel.CurrentIndex()].subcategory;
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    }),
    Menu: [
    {
        subcategory: [
            { name: '1', id: 50000436 },
            { name: '2', id: 50010402 },
            { name: '3', id: 50010159 }
        ],
    }
};
```

And my html:

```
<div class="categories" id="categories">
    <div class="first-category" id="first-category">
        <ul data-bind="foreach:Menu">
            <li data-bind="text:name,attr:{id:id,class:className},event{ mouseover: $root.myfunction}"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-category" id="sub-category">
        <ul data-bind="foreach:CurrentSubCategory()">
            <li><a data-bind="text:name,attr:{href:getListUrl(id)}"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry, can't post images due to less than 10 reputation.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: well.. you need to post source code.. not images when you're referring to the source code..! so the second one should be text..

Comment: It would be a great help, if you create a jsfiddle that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Not sure the code you're displaying is complete or not! But from the looks of it, the "Menu" object is defined as an array...but has no closing "]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several syntax errors in your code which I imagine are a result of your making it simpler to post.

I have posted a working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gy6Gv/2/

I changed Menu to be an observable array only because knockout provides the helper method .indexOf to make it easier to get the index of the menu from the mouseover. Other than that there was no problem with the computed. I imagine there is some other syntactical error in your actual code.

Comment: thanks for your sample , yes, changing Menu to be an observable array and indexof is very good .

Comment: no errors in chrome developer console , i just changed currentIndex , and CurrentSubCategory not updated .